# How is the number of crosses of -180 line calculated from the bode plot?

Tags: circuit-design, stability, bode-plot

On the page 28/46 of the slide [here](https://www.slideshare.net/DummyDummy74/72nyquist-stability-criterionppt):

[image]

On the page 42/46:

**How are N_ and N_ equal to 1/2 here?**

I think it should have been N_ = 0 and N+ = 1.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure slide 27 is correct as what matters is the phase at a loop gain of 1: you can have a negative margin in the area where the loop gain is greater than 1 and the system will remain stable.

Comment: @VerbalKint It's correct according to the theorem that they mentioned on page 28.

Comment: I think it is formulated in an awkward way: the system in 27 is indeed unstable but because the PM at the 0-dB magnitude is still negative, not because of the crossing where the gain is > 1 as a separate argument. This is illustrated in slide 29 where the phase crosses in the region of gain > 1 (as in 27) but then goes back to a positive PM at the 0-dB point. I may be nit-picking but the argument in slide 27 can be misleading if taken alone. Bode stability argument is valid for minimum-phase types of systems, if you add a RHP pole or zero or a delay, it can be deceitful and Nyquist rules.

Comment: @VerbalKint I agree, however I'm looking for a way to check stability using Bode plot even with non-minimum phase system with a RHP pole or zero. Do you aware any rule or theory to do that with Bode only? I understand Nyquist but it's not always available from simulator while bode is.

Comment: You may want to look at this [paper](https://journals.flvc.org/cee/article/view/122951/121980) which gives a different rule for assessing stability with Bode.

Comment: One book that I often refer to for control systems is [Introduction to Continuous and Digital Control Systems](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-continuous-digital-control-systems/dp/B000H4H4WG/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=ZE3UO6527L4B&keywords=Introduction+to+Continuous+and+Digital+Control+Systems&qid=1699454209&sprefix=introduction+to+continuous+and+digital+control+systems%2Caps%2C218&sr=8-1) from Saucedo and Schiring. It is dated from the 70's but all the information it packs on control theory is explained in very intuitive ways and is invaluable.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thanks for the recommendation, I will definitely check it out!

Comment: @VerbalKint Unfortunately the revised Bode stability criterion in the link you sent is only a SUFFICIENCY condition, not a necessary condition. It cannot be used with a conditionally stable system like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwS7M.jpg